# Проблема с API PHP JSON

Tags: php, json, api

PHP код:

```
$version= $_GET['version'];
$key= $_GET['key'];
$client= $_GET['client'];
echo json_encode(array($version));
echo json_encode(array($key));
echo json_encode(array($client));
```

htaccess код:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]*)/(.*)$ api.php?version=$1&key=$2&client=$3 [L]
```

Пишу в url site.com/aaa/bbb/ccc
Выводит:

```
["aaa"]["bbb\/ccc"][""]
```

Comment: Ну так - все после первого слеша идет в `$2`.

Comment: по подробней, я вас не понял

Comment: в reweriteRule первая группа скобок идет в $1 вторая в $2. третьей пары у вас нет, а скобки (.*) захватывают все что есть в строек после второго слеша